# Implements GeoMESA on CDH6

Tags: bigdata, geospatial, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, geomesa

I have cluster of Cloudera with CDH 6.1.
I need to implement solution for geospatial processing based on GeoMESA library.
My solution should read geospatial data from both CSV, and GeoJSON files.

After some research I found that GeoMESA must have storage layer.
As a storage layer, I can choose (as part of CDH packages) either HBase or Accumulo.
I found that the version of HBase in CDH6.1 (HBase 2.2.1) not supported by GeoMESA, and I found a lot of issues during the activation of Accumulo, since Cloudera didn't release version for CDH6.1 (only version for CDH5).

Is anyone implements the GeoMESA library on CDH6?

Please help

Comment: Discussions like this might be easier to have on Gitter or one of the GeoMesa email lists.  See https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa#join-the-community for more info!

Comment: There is a PR up for HBase 2 support that might work for you here: https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/pull/2388